Runtime 4605 in VBA Macro
On running this script that converts fixed notes to Hyperlinked notes in Microsoft Word from Gregmaxey, I am getting runtime 4605 which says that the method or property is unavailable because the object is empty at line which says oRngNoteToCut.Cut. I have tried TIMERUN but to no avail. Could someone check the code and give a solution. Thanks
`Sub ConvertFixedNotesToWordNotes()
'Coded by Paul Edstein and Greg Maxey.

'The default note reference ID enumerator in the text is a Arabic format number
'enclosed in square-brackets (i.e., \[#\])
'The default note enumerator for each note at the end of the document is "Note #:"
'You can redefine either default value at run time.

'The fixed notes should be located at the end of the document or, with multi-sectional
'notes, the end of the section; otherwise extraneous text will be incorporated.
'If manual page breaks are contained within the notes range, the affected notes will
'be truncated at that point.

'Note numbering may be contiguous, incomplete or restart (e.g., at 1 in each section).
'The output applies sequential numbering, but that's easily addressed manually afterwards.

'Notes must be delimited from each other by a paragraph mark or a table's end-marker.
'Notes may contain multiple paragraphs and tables.

'When converted, the default footnote/endnote text paragraph style is applied to each
'paragraph in the note (except for table text). Any character style formatting applied
'to original notes is preserved. Direct formatting applied to original single paragraph
'notes is preserved. Formatting in tables is preserved.

Dim strNoteEnum As String, strNote_ID As String, strNoteType As String
Dim bSuperscript As Boolean, bFound As Boolean
Dim lngIndex As Long, lngNoteCount As Long, lngCount As Long, i As Long
Dim oDoc As Word.Document, oRng As Word.Range, oRngNotes As Word.Range
Dim oRngRef As Word.Range, oRngNoteToCut As Word.Range, oRngNote As Word.Range
Dim oPar As Paragraph
Dim StrChars As String, StrChr As String, strLS As String, strSty As String

Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
Set oRng = oDoc.Range
strLS = Application.International(wdListSeparator)
bFound = False

'Get variable values from user. Exit if there's an input error.
On Error GoTo lbl_Exit
strNoteType = InputBox("What type of notes do you want to convert -" \_
& vbCr & "1. Footnotes" & vbCr & "2. Endnotes" \_
& vbCr & vbCr & "Please input 1 or 2 for the note type.", \_
"Note Type Determination", "1")
If strNoteType \< 1 Or strNoteType \> 2 Then GoTo lbl_Exit

strNoteEnum = InputBox("Enter the text string that identifies\\enumerates " \_
& "each note in the notes text." & vbCr & vbCr \_
& "Be sure to use:" & vbCr & "o ""#"" to represent Arabic numbers " \_
& "(e.g. ""Note #:"")." \_
& vbCr & "o ""x"" to represent Roman numerals (e.g. ""Note x:"").", \_
"Note Enumerator", "Note #:")
If StrPtr(strNoteEnum) = 0 Then GoTo lbl_Exit

strNote_ID = InputBox("Enter the text string that flags each note reference " \_
& "enumerator ID in the document text.  " & vbCr & vbCr \_
& "Be sure to include any leading spaces and to use:" \_
& vbCr & "o ""#"" to represent Arabic numbers (e.g. ""\[#\]"")." \_
& vbCr & "o ""x"" to represent Roman numerals (e.g. ""\[x\]"").", \_
"Note Enumerator Reference", "\[#\]")
If StrPtr(strNoteEnum) = 0 Then GoTo lbl_Exit

If MsgBox("Is the reference ID enumerator text superscripted?", \_
vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Supercript") = vbYes Then
bSuperscript = True
Else
bSuperscript = False
End If
'Restore normal error handling.
On Error GoTo 0

'Parse the input strings for processing. The characters in StrChars need '' prefixes.
'Roman numerals need to be fully expressed, in upper & lower case forms.
StrChars = "\[,\],{,},(,)"
For i = 0 To UBound(Split(StrChars, ","))
StrChr = Split(StrChars, ",")(i)
strNoteEnum = Replace(strNoteEnum, StrChr, "" & StrChr)
strNote_ID = Replace(strNote_ID, StrChr, "" & StrChr)
Next
strNoteEnum = Replace(strNoteEnum, "#", "\[0-9\]{1" & strLS & "3}")
strNoteEnum = Replace(strNoteEnum, "x", "\[iIvVxXlLcC\]{1" & strLS & "11}")
strNote_ID = Replace(strNote_ID, "#", "\[0-9\]{1" & strLS & "3}")
strNote_ID = Replace(strNote_ID, "x", "\[iIvVxXlLcCdD\]{1" & strLS & "11}")

With oRng
'Look for fixed note references.
With .Find
.ClearFormatting
.Replacement.ClearFormatting
.Text = strNote_ID
.Format = True
.Font.Superscript = bSuperscript
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
.MatchWholeWord = True
.MatchWildcards = True
.Execute
End With
'Was a note reference found?
If .Find.Found = False Then
MsgBox "No fixed Note Reference was found.", \_
vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "No Note References"
GoTo lbl_Exit
End If

    'Loop through the document and identify all fixed note content.
    oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Do
      With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = strNoteEnum
        .Format = False
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchWildcards = True
        If .Execute Then Beep
      End With
      'Was any text matching the defined fixed note enumerator found?
      Do While .Find.Found = True
        'Is it a "qualified" instance (i.e., starts a new paragraph)?
        If .Duplicate.Start = .Duplicate.Paragraphs.First.Range.Start Then
          bFound = True
          Exit Do
        End If
        .Find.Execute
      Loop
      'Was a "qualified" fixed note enumerator found?
      If bFound = False Then
        MsgBox "No fixed Note Content was found.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "No Note Content"
        GoTo lbl_Exit
      End If
      'Reset the working fixed notes range.
      Set oRngNotes = .Duplicate
      With oRngNotes
        'Kill the fixed note enumerator text.
        .Text = vbNullString
        'Attempt to extend the range to the next section break or manual page break.
        .MoveEndUntil Cset:=Chr(12)
        'Was the range endpoint moved?  If not, extend it to the document end.
        If .Start = .End Then .End = oDoc.Range.End
        'Each fixed note must end with a paragraph mark.
        'If the last character is not a paragraph break, insert one.
        If .Characters.Last <> vbCr Then .InsertAfter vbCr
      End With
      'Find and count any remaining notes.
      .Find.Wrap = wdFindStop
      Do While .Find.Found = True
        'Are we still in the notes range?
        If .Duplicate.InRange(oRngNotes) = True Then
          'Is the reference at the start of a paragraph?
          If .Duplicate.Start = .Duplicate.Paragraphs.First.Range.Start Then
            lngNoteCount = lngNoteCount + 1
          End If
        Else
          Exit Do
        End If
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Find.Execute
      Loop
      If lngNoteCount = lngIndex Then GoTo lbl_Exit
      'Let Word do its housekeeping.
      DoEvents
      'Replace static fixed note reference IDs with dynamic notes.
      For lngIndex = 1 To lngNoteCount
        'Find the static reference ID.
        With .Find
          .Text = strNote_ID
          .Wrap = wdFindContinue
          .Format = True
          .Font.Superscript = bSuperscript
          .MatchWholeWord = True
          .MatchWildcards = True
          .Execute
        End With
        If .Find.Found Then
          'Define a working Note reference range.
          Set oRngRef = .Duplicate
          'Kill the fixed note reference ID.
          oRngRef.Text = vbNullString
          'Define a working note range to cut.
          Set oRngNoteToCut = oRngNotes.Duplicate
          If lngIndex < lngNoteCount Then
            'Define the indexed fixed note range by looking for the *next*
            'fixed note enumerator.
            With oRngNotes.Duplicate
              With .Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = strNoteEnum
                .Format = False
                .MatchWildcards = True
                .Execute
              End With
              'Was the *next* enumerator text found?
              If .Find.Found Then
                'Fix the range to cut end point.
                oRngNoteToCut.End = .Start
                  'Kill the *next* fixed note enumerator.
                  .Text = vbNullString
              End If
            End With
          End If
          'Place the fixed note text in the clipboard.
          oRngNoteToCut.Cut
          If strNoteType = 1 Then
            'Create an empty dynamic footnote.
            .Footnotes.Add Range:=oRngRef, Text:=""
            i = oDoc.Footnotes.Count
            Set oRngNote = oDoc.Footnotes(i).Range
            strSty = oRngNote.Style
          Else
            'Create an empty dynamic endnote.
            .Endnotes.Add Range:=oRngRef, Text:=""
            i = oDoc.Endnotes.Count
            Set oRngNote = oDoc.Endnotes(i).Range
            strSty = oRngNote.Style
            
          End If
          StatusBar = "Creating Note: " & i
          'Insert the note content.
          With oRngNote
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            .Paste
            .End = .End + 1
            While .Characters.Last.Previous = vbCr
              .Characters.Last.Previous.Text = vbNullString
            Wend
            'Note: If you incorporate multiple paragraphs in your fixed notes, the
            'default footnote paragraph will be reapplied to them (except for tables).
            For lngCount = 1 To .Paragraphs.Count - 1
              If .Paragraphs(lngCount).Range.Information(wdWithInTable) = False Then
                .Paragraphs(lngCount).Style = strSty
              End If
            Next lngCount
          End With
        End If
        'Let Word do its housekeeping.
        DoEvents
      Next lngIndex
      'Reset the index and counter and look for another set of fixed note enumerators.
      lngIndex = 0: lngCount = 0
    Loop Until oRngNotes.End = oDoc.Range.End

End With
With oDoc
While .Characters.Last.Previous = vbCr
.Characters.Last.Previous.Text = vbNullString
Wend
End With
lbl_Exit:
Set oRng = Nothing: Set oRngNotes = Nothing: Set oRngRef = Nothing
Set oRngNoteToCut = Nothing: Set oRngNote = Nothing: Set oDoc = Nothing
StatusBar = "Done!!"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Have tried TIMERUN and DoEvents.

Did you read the extensive notes at the top of the code, then: (1) ensure your document layout conforms to the macro's requirements; and (2) supply the correct inputs at each of the prompts? From your problem description, it seems you have some content that evaluates as an empty endnote. I have no idea what TIMERUN is and the macro already has its own DoEvents code.

@macropod yes the instructions are being complied with. I have tested it on small sample. It works sometimes. And, the interesting thing is that it gives the error at random notes. It is not even the same note everytime.

Just an observation, but the code as posted here has introduced a lot of backslash characters \ that are not in the code posted by Greg Maxey at https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/convert_reference_notes_to_dynamic_footnotes.html . Some of these cause syntax errors, e.g.  "\_" at line end, but others are not so obvious (e.g. the ones in here should not be there: strNoteEnum = Replace(strNoteEnum, "#", "\[0-9\]{1" & strLS & "3}") . The problem is that instead of a Find what specification like \[[0-9]{1,3}\] the code as posted uses  \[\[0-9\]{1,3}\] , which is not what is needed.

@jonsson I have solved the problem with using .formattedtext instead of cut and paste. However, now I am getting another issue which is that the script is getting stuck on DoEvents instead after a specific number of notes.

Update: I have removed the DoEvents and now it just becomes non-responsive after creating some number of notes.

At this point, it's probably better to post a new Question with your updated code. FWIW it's quite hard to find errors in reasonably well-tested code (which I am pretty sure this was) without test data that lets people replicate the problem quite easily. Meanwhile, just a guess but do you have a very large number of notes to convert?

@jonsson To answer your question, I have a lot of notes to convert but I am testing it on smaller files first. Nevertheless, I will make a new post.
